# Get profile of firefox ProfilesIni not selecting given profiles when profile count more than 3 including default

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Below code didn't changed FF profile when I am having 3(randomly created nos.) custom FF profiles and 1 default.

```
WebDriver driver;
    String profilepath = "<user Dir>/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/";
    ProfilesIni profilesini = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(profilepath));
    firefoxprofile = profilesini.getProfile("profile_1");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxprofile);
```

FF profiles are : profile_1, profile_2 and profile_3. When I run the code FF launched with either 'profile_2 or default'. Not with passed profile name (profile_1)

Am using selenium-sever standalone 2.53.0 and FF 46.0 on Win 10, 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch a custom firefox profile. This is how you do it.

First you create an object of `ProfilesIni` then you get the desired `firefox profile` using `getProfile()` and then that particular profile is passed to `WebDriver` initialization.

```
ProfilesIni profiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = profiles.getProfile("profile_1");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did same way (specifying path to my FF profile directory - {FirefoxProfile firefoxprofile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(profilepath));}). But how it is behaving, FFprofile object picks first time with passed profile value. Next run, if I change 'profile name' and run, FF launched with previous profile only not the current run profile name.